# How to use Auto Registration and Type Scanning in Structuremap

Tags: c#, structuremap, structuremap3

In my solution I have three projects like this.
[image]

I copy Common.dll and Service.dll in a folder like  d:\libs and use the below code with type scan

```
 ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
           {
              x.Scan(xx =>
               {
                   xx.AssembliesFromPath(@"d:\libs");
                   xx.LookForRegistries();
               });
           });
//I have PersonService that implement IPersonService
namespace Common
{
    public interface IPersonService
    {
        string SayHello(string name);
    }
}
namespace Services
{
    public class PersonService : IPersonService
    {
        public string SayHello(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("Hello {0}", name);
        }
    }
}
```

After Initialize my dependencies when I want get instance from IPerson I get this error

```
  var personService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IPersonService>();
```

> {"No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'Common.IPersonService'\r\n\r\nThere is no configuration specified for Common.IPersonService\r\n\r\n1.) Container.GetInstance(Common.IPersonService)\r\n"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add `xx.WithDefaultConventions();` as well.
- And when you are designing a plugin system by using StructureMap, the host project shouldn't have a reference to any of the plugins. Only the interface/contract plugin should be referenced and this assembly shouldn't be copied to `d:\libs` folder. In other words, the current application domain shouldn't have 2 instances of any assemblies. So if you want to use `IPersonService` interface in the host program directly, add a reference to `Common.dll` and don't copy it to `d:\libs` folder to avoid duplication. And now the host project shouldn't have a reference to `Services.dll` too.

Comment: I add xx.WithDefaultConventions(); and remove  refrence to services.dll ...But i get the erorr .does my scan code must change?

Comment: No. Delete the `Common.dll` file from the `d:\libs` folder too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WithDefaultConventions()` in your call to `Scan` which will internally use a `DefaultConventionScanner`.

You can read the source code or look at the documentation but it does this:

```
var interfaceName = "I" + concreteType.Name;
return concreteType.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == interfaceName);
```

During a default convention scan, each concrete type scanned will look for the first interface of the class name preceded by the letter "I".  Therefore, while scanning, `IFooService` with be automatically registered and assigned if `FooService` is found during the scan, therefore allowing you to not have to explicitly say

`For<IFooService>().Use<FooService>()`

The exception you are seeing will always be thrown when there is no registered concrete implementation for the type you requested.

Answer (score 0):

The types you expected to be registered are not because you are scaning with *xx.LookForRegistries()* which looks for StructureMap registries (you can read more about registries here - http://structuremap.github.io/registration/registry-dsl/). If you create such registries with proper registrations then SM will find them and registeres.

As already mentioned the altrernative is to use *xx.WithDefaultConventions()*. Take a look at this edge case when using default convention the expected type was not registered - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27449018/4336786